# maven eclipse taglib compile warning

Tags: eclipse, maven, taglib

I am trying out creating Spring MVC app on SpringToolSuite (STS) IDE.

I do: New> Spring Template Project > Spring MVC app

It seems to get set up OK, except that the JSP file keep showing a red line for the JSTL tag lib.

I can't figure out what's wrong, because the project does have "Maven Dependencies" library that lists the servlet-api-2.5.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, and jsp-api-2.1.jar

This is my first foray into a Maven app..

Any idea why the JSP editor is showing red line for the taglib?

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the Error went away I did a "Clean". Looks like all it needed was a refresh.